# p:inputText size attribute doesn't limit allowed text length

Tags: primefaces

I am using `p:inputText` and the `size` attribute does not effectively limit the number of allowed characters in the field:

```
<p:inputText id="limitedField" title="Limited Field" 
        size="16" required="true"
        styleClass="plainInput"
        value="#{entity.limitedField}" />
```

First of all, the user is physically allowed to enter more 16 characters. Secondly, when they do, instead of a graceful message displayed to the user in the front end they entered an invalid value, which should be a provision of the JSF framework error, they get a generic exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "MYSCHEMA"."MY_TABLE"."LIMITED_FIELD" (actual: 22, maximum: 16)
```

I looked into the generated HTML and there is indeed a size attribute given to the text input but it is not effective:

```
<input id="..." name="limitedField" type="text" size="16" title="Limited Field"" aria-required="true" class="..." />
```

I thought simply setting the size attribute would prevent invalidly sized data to even be attempted to be written in the DB but apparently not.  How do I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between "maxlength" & "size" attribute in html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247565/difference-between-maxlength-size-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try maxlength attribute

`maxlength="16"`

Comment: IMO, having two different attributes for size and maxlength, while i understand the difference, is one of those nuances that overcomplicates matters more than does it benefit from "sophistication".  i think there should just be one setting and it means how many characters you can put in the field.  things should be kept simple

Comment: Then create a new custom/composite component. Not everybody wants it that way. I have ui's where, for making it have not all kinds of inputs with different physical size, I give them the same size but with a different max length. Complain at the w3c